# HTML Compressor | Line breaks needed?

Tags: html

I'm minifying my html using:

http://htmlcompressor.com/compressor.html

It leaves return characters in so instead of one single line...I get a bunch of individual lines.

Any reason why?(JS and CSS minifiers do not do this)  Any experience with this for html minification?  Is this a solid tool?

Comment: It's just an option... click "Show options" on the right and you can specify "single line html output".

Comment: thanks...I can test no line breaks ...if it doesn't break anything per below...might as wells strip them

Comment: it's leaving a single space in between my tags...is this needed as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newlines can affect the output, so they can't really be safely stripped from every HTML document.

For example:

```
​<p>
Hello
World
</p>

<p>HelloWorld</p>​
```

This gets rendered as:

```
Hello World
HelloWorld
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UTy2f/**